# In search for a counterexample related to the Abel-Stolz theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, summation-method

**Edit**: [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394773/in-search-for-a-counterexample-related-to-the-abel-stolz-theorem) to the MathOverflow with some with some modifications in order to answer to questions posed in the comments. Now it has an accepted answer by Pietro Majer and a very interesting answer by Alexandre Eremenko.

**Definition 1**. A *curve in the complex plane* is the image $\gamma([a,b])$ of a segment $[a,b]\subseteq\Bbb R$ through a continuous non constant function $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb C$: the points $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ are called *endpoints* of the curve.
With abuse of notation, the curve is identified with its defining continuous function $\gamma$ (which is really simply *a parametrization* of the curve).
**Definition 2**. A complex sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is said *Abel-summable* if, for  $x\in [0,1]$, $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is finite: if $s\in\Bbb C$ is the value of the limit, this is usually written as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n= s\;(\mathrm{A})$.
**Definition 3**. A Stolz region $\Bbb {St}(M)$ in the unit disk $\Bbb D\triangleq \{z\in\Bbb C: |z|^2\le1\}$ is the set
$$
\Bbb {St}(M)\triangleq \big\{z\in \Bbb D : |1-z|\leq M(1-|z|)\big\} \quad M>1.
$$
Be it noted that if $M=1$ then $\Bbb {St}(M)=[0,1]$, while if $M<1$ then $\Bbb {St}(M)=\emptyset$, therefore the condition $M>1$ is simply a non-triviality condition.
**Theorem (Abel-Stolz)**. Let $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb C$ be a complex sequence  such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=s\in\Bbb C$. Then the power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges to $s$ along every curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ with $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(1)=1$ and $\gamma\subset\Bbb{St}(M)$: moreover the convergence is uniform for every point $z\in \Bbb{St}(M)$.

**My question**:

> do there exist a divergent but Abel summable sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb C$ for which $f(z)$ does not converge uniformly on the "deleted" Stolz region $\Bbb{St}(M)\setminus\{ 1\}$?

**Some notes and why I am interested**

- A (sketchy) proof of Abel-Stolz theorem can be found in the [related wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). For an historical survey on the various proofs and extension of this theorem see the first paragraph of Hardy's paper [1], while Knopp [2] offers a detailed analysis in §8, theorem 4 p.74, theorem 5 p. 74, §52, theorem 1 pp. 391-392.
- The problem was motivated by a research on [Fatou's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_theorem): in particular, during the reading of [3] I found that any $f(z)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=s$ converges to $s$ along every path $\gamma\subset\Bbb{St}(M)$ with endpoints $0$ and $1$ and is bounded on $\Bbb {St}(M)$ (I had to find a proof by myself, since Privalov consider this fact as obvious and thus does not give an explicit proof).

**References**

[1] Godfrey Harold Hardy, "Some theorems connected with Abel’s theorem on the continuity of power series". (English) Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society (2) 4, 247-265 (1906), [JFM 37.0429.01](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A37.0429.01).

[2] Konrad Knopp, *Theory and Application of Infinite Series*, Translated from the 2nd ed. and revised in accordance with the fourth by R. C. H. Young, London-Glasgow: Blackie & Son,
1951, XII+563, [Zbl 0042.29203](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0042.29203).

[3] Ivan Ivanovich Privalov, "[Sur une généralisation du théorème de Fatou](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/msb6849)" (Russian, French abstract) Recueil Mathématique Moscou (Matematicheskiĭ Sbornik) 31, 232-235 (1923), [JFM 49.0225.02](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A49.0225.02).

Comment: You can add $\sum_{n>0}\frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2\cdot 3^n}}{n}$ and $\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^nz^n$. The resulting series is not summable, since the coefficients don't tend to zero. The sequence of coefficients is Abel summable, since first series has non-tangential limits at $z=1$ by Abel's theorem and the second is $\frac{1}{1+z}$. The second series has limits when $z\to 1$ regardless of how you approach $1$ from inside the unit disc, but the first one doesn't have non-non-tangential limit. So, the sum cannot have non-non-tangential limit either.

Comment: @plop, it is true that the sum of functions you suggest does not converge in $z=1$, but both the functions you consider have non-tangential limits, so their sum does: and also I am asking for an example of power series for which the non-tangential limit exists (and this is implied by Abel summability) and it does not uniformly converge on the associated Stolz region.

Comment: I read "deleted" as the complement of the Stolz angle. I see now that you mean in(side) $\mathbb{St}(M)\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: @plop exactly: I've used the term "deleted" in the sense of the "deleted neighborhood" of singular integrals. It is really an abuse of notation, though it recalls quicly the idea of removing a point from the adherence of a given set.